# Why a JS function returns different results in C++?

Tags: c++

A riddle:

You have 3 catalogs. Each of them contains 2 catalogs. Each of those catalogs contains 1 catalog, and those are empty. How many catalogs do you have?

I wrote a JavaScript function to solve it…

```
function catalogsNumber(c)
{ 
    n = 0;

    for (a = 0; a < c; a++) {
        n = (n + 1) * (a + 1);
    }

    return n;
}
```

…and it returns correct results:

```
// Results in JavaScript
catalogsNumber ( 3 ) => 15
catalogsNumber ( 4 ) => 64
catalogsNumber ( 5 ) => 325
catalogsNumber ( 12 ) => 1302061344
catalogsNumber ( 13 ) => 16926797485
catalogsNumber ( 14 ) => 236975164804
```

But when I tried the same in C++, the function returned strange results every time when `c > 12`:

```
int catalogsNumber(int c)
{
    int i, n = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        n = (n + 1) * (i + 1);
    }

    return n;
}

// Results in С++
catalogsNumber ( 3 ) => 15              // correct
catalogsNumber ( 4 ) => 64              // correct
catalogsNumber ( 5 ) => 325             // correct
catalogsNumber ( 12 ) => 1302061344     // correct
catalogsNumber ( 13 ) => -253071699     // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
catalogsNumber ( 14 ) => 751963524      // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```

Such a riddle, very mystery. Why does it happen?

Comment: Try change int to long int in C++.

Comment: Because the result is bigger than an int value so it will return -xxxxxx. change it to long instead

Comment: `long` doesn't offer any guarantee. On some platforms long is the same width as `int`. Use `std::int64_t` or `std::uint64_t`

Comment: Please don't add the answer to the question. There is a clear distinction here between an answer and a question. If you want to show appreciation you can upvote the helpful answers and you should accept the answer that solved your problem. I've rolled back you edit that added the solution and thanks.

Comment: @bolov or find an arbitrary precision integer library and use that for catalogsNumber ( 30 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are overflowing the `int` variable n, which has a max value of 2,147,483,647.

You need to use a wider type. You can use an `unsigned int` type, which doubles your maximum value, however this wont help much in this case. So better would be to use a 64-bit integer.

```
uint64_t catalogsNumber(int c)
{
    int i=0;
    uint64_t n = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        n = (n + 1) * (i + 1);
    }

    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an overflow: when called with 13, the result doesn't fit in your `int` variable.

Answer (score 0):

There is an overflow. You are trying to store at an integer a value that is bigger than the value an integer can hold. 
The javascript works because it is an untyped language, so you don't declare the type of your output variable and compiler finds itself and allocates the needed memory.
To solve the problem, in c/c++ you should declare your variable as type long, or long long. 
Hope that helps:)

Answer (score -1):

Change i to a short and make the result n an uint64_t so it will not give an overflow exception. You can not store the value 16926797485 in an int

```
int catalogsNumber(int c)
{
 // Change to long int instead of int or some other bigger datatype, 
 // the value can't be stored inside an int
  short i = 0;
  uint64_t int n = 0; 

  for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
      n = (n + 1) * (i + 1);
  }

   return n;
 }
```

Comment: on some platforms (VS on x86 and x64 for example) `long` is the same width as `int`

Comment: better to use uint64_t instead. Also, your `i` variable is now also 64bits, (if long equal to 64bits), so better to split the declaration of `i` and `n`.